# I set xgamma at startup, but it resets

Tags: startup, monitor

I have a startup command to set my gamma in xgamma; whenever I log in, it flickers briefly to what I have it set to, then goes back to 1. Why?
Is there a better way to adjust gamma defaults?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run xrandr commands at startup in Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/637911/how-to-run-xrandr-commands-at-startup-in-ubuntu)

Comment: see futher below in the answer:  http://askubuntu.com/a/637921/72216 : "Important note: adding xrandr commands to Startup Applications" There is no difference with setting `xrandr` commands on startup (log in).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

The solution for me was to set a sleep command in the bash script for 10 seconds to delay the initiation.

```
#! /bin/sh
sleep 10
xgamma -rgamma x.xxx -ggamma x.xxx -bgamma x.xxx
```

This seems to work on 12.10 with HD 4000 graphics (mesa driver)

(If you need to create a script, you open your text editor, paste the lines above in the text file, chage x.xxx values to what you need, and save the file with *.sh name (* is you file name))

(Than you want to add script to start up applications, type start up in unity bar, and than add the file in the new window)

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Add the `xgamma -gamma x.xxx` command to `~/.xinitrc`