# How to make gamma settings on Ubuntu 14.04 permanent?

Tags: 14.04, resolution, display

I need to change my monitor's gamma settings permanently to the value of 0.7. I've tried using `xgamma` for this, but the thing is I have to execute this command everytime I start my laptop. Also, the gamma settings seem to revert to their original values (1.0) if something *significant* happens - when I copy/delete something, when I play media from my external hard disk, etc.
I tried making a custom script which reads like:

```
#!/bin/bash
xgamma -gamma 0.7
```

Saved it as `gammasettings.sh`, put it up into my list of start-up applications; but it fails to work for some reason.

Changing these settings again and again is a really cumbersome. Is there a way to make these changes permanent (edit any `.conf` file or something)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I set xgamma at startup, but it resets](http://askubuntu.com/questions/266050/i-set-xgamma-at-startup-but-it-resets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install redshift,  `sudo apt-get install redshift`
2. In terminal, `gnome-session-properties`
3. Add `redshift -t 6500k:6500k -g .7:.7:.7` (the first 6500k is temp color for day, the second for night, - 6500k is default temp color- you can change the values) (.7 is my gamma setting)
4. Install dconf-editor `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`
5. Open dconf-editor, org->gnome ->gnome-session and check "auto-save-session"
6. Reboot

Answer (score 1):

Redshift applies *additional* gamma correction, so it may not play nicely with xgamma (i.e. together they may over-correct).

My solution is:

1. Put `xgamma -quiet -gamma 0.7` in session/Application Autostart
2. Put `redshift-gtk` (without gamma setting, but you can use `-l LAT:LONG` parameter for if location service fails) in session/Application Autostart
3. Have a link to run `xgamma -gamma 0.7` in case something deactivates the correction

Then you can deactivate Redshift temporarily, say for watching a video, and it will not affect the gamma.

Answer (score 0):

Make executable gammasettings.sh

```
chmod +x gammasettings.sh
```

Then modify the script like this

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 1
xgamma -gamma 0.7
```

On my VAIO with Ubuntu 14.04 works like a charm :)

Comment: How do I set it only for a specific display?  The tool takes a `display` and a `screen` argument, but how do I find the right values for these parameters?