# How to run xrandr commands at startup in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, display, xrandr, startup-applications, display-resolution

How can I run the following `xrandr`command on startup?

xrandr

```
cvt 1368 768 
xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1368x768_60.00
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1368x768_60.00
```

Comment: Hi Udhaya Kumar did you notice you have an answer? Please let me know if you manage.

Answer (score 26):

#### Adding complicated commands to Startup Applications

In General, you can add commands to run on start up (log in) by choosing: Dash > Startup Applications > Add. In this case, you have a *complicated* command to run.

There are two options to do that:

1. write a separate script:

   ```bsh
   #!/bin/bash

   cvt 1368 768 
   # xrandr only works in X11 sessions, not Wayland
   [ "$XDG_SESSION_TYPE" = x11 ] || exit 0
   xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
   xrandr --addmode VGA1 1368x768_60.00
   xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1368x768_60.00
   ```

   Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `set_monitor.sh`
   and add the following command to startup applications as described above.

   ```
   /bin/bash /path/to/set_monitor.sh
   ```
2. Chain the commands to one (very long) command:

   ```
    /bin/bash -c "cvt 1368 768&&xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync&&xrandr --addmode VGA1 1368x768_60.00&&xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1368x768_60.00"
   ```

   In this case, using `&&` between the commands will make each command run as soon (and if) the previous one is run succesfully, just like they are on separate lines.

   Then add the command to Startup Applications, as described above.

#### Important note: adding xrandr commands to Startup Applications

Adding `xrandr` commands to startup can be tricky; sometimes they break if they are run too early, before the desktop is fully loaded. Therefore you might (probably) need to add a little break into the command to (either) run the script or the command, like (in the last case):

```
/bin/bash -c "sleep 15&&cvt 1368 768&&xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync&&xrandr --addmode VGA1 1368x768_60.00&&xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1368x768_60.00"
```

You might need to play a little with the `sleep 15`to find the optimal time.

#### Note

I left out the first line:

```
xrandr
```

since it does nothin but display some information on your screen setup :)

Comment: You don't need to include the `cvt` command if you already know your modeline.

Comment: The `/bin/bash -c "..."` wrapping did the trick for me :)

Comment: On Kubuntu 17.10, I added the command without the `sleep` part in 'Startup applications' by selecting the "Before Session startup" option.

Comment: +1 for writing 3 years ago `# xrandr only works in X11 sessions, not Wayland`. Good future proofing back then.

Comment: This solution finally worked in my Debian 10 with two monitors: Apple Thunderbolt 27 + LG 27MP59G. Natively, the LG supports only 1920x1080. With `xrandr` I set it up at the same resolution of the Tunderbolt of 2560x1440 with `/bin/bash -c "sleep 3&&xrandr --output DP-2 --auto --scale-from 2560x1440"`.

Comment: Thank you so much - your time and expertise is greatly appreciated.  I will execute this later today when the grandchildren have left!  Thanks once again. Duncan

Comment: @Duncan greatgreat, say hello from the grandchildren from me :)

Answer (score 11):

According to [this](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Xorg_RandR_1.2) at the **Now automate it on login** section, I have made my own script `45custom_xrandr-settings` and placed it into `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/`. It works fine for me under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. You could place the code below after the `case` command described in that section.

```bsh
PRI_OUTPUT="DVI-0";
# Make and force resolution
myNewMode=$(cvt 1366 768 60 | grep -oP 'Modeline\K.*') &&                           #grep evrything after 'Modline'
myNewModeName=\"$(echo $myNewMode | grep -oP '"\K[^"\047]+(?=["\047])' )\" &&       #grep everything inside quotes
xrandr --newmode $myNewMode;
sleep 15;       
xrandr --addmode $PRI_OUTPUT $myNewModeName;
```

I believe that the above is what you are looking for. You can see the available outputs simply by running the `xrandr` command. The outputs may be `VGA`, `VGA-0`, `DVI-0`, `TMDS-1` or `DisplayPort-0`.

Here is the complete script that I made.

```bsh
# To configure xrandr automatically during the first login, 
# save this script to your computer as /etc/X11/Xsession.d/45custom_xrandr-settings: 

# If an external monitor is connected, place it with xrandr
# External output may be "VGA" or "VGA-0" or "DVI-0" or "TMDS-1"

# More info at http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Xorg_RandR_1.2


PRI_OUTPUT="DVI-0";
SEC_OUTPUT="DisplayPort-0";
SEC_LOCATION="left";    # SEC_LOCATION may be one of: left, right, above, or below

case "$SEC_LOCATION" in
       left|LEFT)
               SEC_LOCATION="--left-of $PRI_OUTPUT"
               ;;
       right|RIGHT)
               SEC_LOCATION="--right-of $PRI_OUTPUT"
               ;;
       top|TOP|above|ABOVE)
               SEC_LOCATION="--above $PRI_OUTPUT"
               ;;
       bottom|BOTTOM|below|BELOW)
               SEC_LOCATION="--below $PRI_OUTPUT"
               ;;
       *)
               SEC_LOCATION="--left-of $PRI_OUTPUT"
               ;;
esac

# Make and force resolution
myNewMode=$(cvt 1366 768 60 | grep -oP 'Modeline\K.*') &&                           #grep evrything after 'Modline'
myNewModeName=\"$(echo $myNewMode | grep -oP '"\K[^"\047]+(?=["\047])' )\" &&       #grep everything inside quotes
xrandr --newmode $myNewMode;
sleep 15;       
xrandr --addmode $PRI_OUTPUT $myNewModeName;


# Activate secondary out (display port)
xrandr | grep $SEC_OUTPUT | grep " connected "
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
#   xrandr --output $SEC_OUTPUT --auto $SEC_LOCATION
    xrandr --output $PRI_OUTPUT --mode $myNewModeName --output $SEC_OUTPUT --auto $SEC_LOCATION
else
    xrandr --output $PRI_OUTPUT --mode $myNewModeName --output $SEC_OUTPUT --off
fi
```

Comment: Thank you very much - your time and expertise is GREATLY appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: This method works perfectly, it just doesn't do it at the login screen but after you login and start a sesssion. I can live with that though.

Answer (score 4):

Create the file `~/.xprofile` and put your lines in it. It is ran at the beginning of the X user session.

Comment: this didnt work. commands fire up  too  early.

Comment: @neckTwi Thanks, I found that `xrandr --output ...` doesn't work but the previous two lines works. All in all this works for me.

Comment: .xsessionrc works for me - but I use xinit and not gdm/lightdm etc

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get the script in /etc/x11/xsession.d to execute, however I used the method described to add the script to startup applications.  I also added a sleep 15 line to the script just in case.

I used an xrandr command inside a text file in a hidden directory.

Comment: So you did what Jacob Vlijm wrote in [his answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/637921/1157519)?