# How to permanently set a custom resolution?

Tags: xrandr, display-resolution

I'm using bootable persistent USB key. I think there are some display problems, so I have to set resolution manually. These commands do it right:

```
sudo xrandr --newmode "1440x900_60.00"  106.50  1440 1528 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync
sudo xrandr --addmode VGA1 1440x900_60.00
sudo xrandr -s 1440x900
```

It would be great if I wouldn't need to manually run these every time my machine starts.

Comment: Please see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/637911/how-to-run-xrandr-commands-at-startup-in-ubuntu/637921#637921 The answer was neglected by OP there, but works :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a GUI frontend to Xrandr, for example [ARandR](http://christian.amsuess.com/tools/arandr/).

ARandR is designed to provide a simple visual front end for XRandR. Relative monitor positions are shown graphically and can be changed in a drag-and-drop way.

Quoted From http://christian.amsuess.com/tools/arandr/:

> Features: Saving configurations as executable shell scripts
>   (configurations can be loaded without using this program)

[image]

After choosing your suitable configuration Then apply the new configuration by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

To install it in Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install arandr
```

Now your configuration will be stored and loaded within the startup

Comment: It's not storing my configuration.

Comment: you use ARandr or xrandr?

Comment: did you Apply your configuration??

Comment: Yes, applied, rebooted and it didn't come up.

Comment: @TellMeWhy the link is broken.