# Fixing screen resolution for Samsung 15.6 inches monitor (Res: 1366x768) while not showing the full screen

Tags: display-resolution

[image]

**How can I solve this problem that after installing Ubuntu mate 18.04.5, the monitor doesn't show its full screen?
Please help me!**

Answer (score 0):

I had this before, my fix was changing my refresh rate from 60hz to 59hz. However I see yours detects as a 16" screen in your picture instead of 15.6.

Answer (score 0):

xrandr is your friends

Try these command

```
xrandr
xrandr --listmonitors
xrandr --prop
```

What you want to is perhaps something like that:

```
xrandr -s 1440x900 -r 60
```

If no definition is available, you can use custom config:
[How to permanently set a custom resolution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/642617/how-to-permanently-set-a-custom-resolution)
[How do I set a custom resolution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-do-i-set-a-custom-resolution)