# Force resolution and make it stay on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: dell, display-resolution, xrandr

I use Ubuntu `15.10` on my dell Ultrasmall optiplex 760 with a 19" dell display.
My display supports a resolution of `1280x1024`. But when I start ubuntu the resolution is `1024x768`.

After long time googling i have found a solution to be able to force my resolution to `1280x1024` by using these commands in terminal:

```
sudo cvt 1280 1024 60
sudo xrandr --newmode "1280x1024_60.00"  109.00  1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync
sudo xrandr --addmode VGA1 1280x1024_60.00
```

But when I restart Ubuntu I have to put these commands in the terminal again because the resolution doesn't stay at bootup.

I've found a lot of topics about this to make the resolution stay but none have worked for me because of missing files which I had to edit in order to make it stay at bootup.

Any help would be appreciated as I have been looking to solve this issue for almost a day.

Keep in mind I am a real noob, and therefore every step to take for a solution should be explained to me step by step.

Thanks.

Comment: No need for `sudo`. In fact you shouldn't when running from Startup Applications.

Comment: But I am not running it from startup I don't know how. I just type these commands in the terminal myself.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/a/637921/72216 in the duplicate link in the first comment. Please mention if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `xrandr` configurations to a startup file, so that you'll get your desired resolution upon reboot/startup:

- Create a bash script, `xrandr.sh` for example, and place your xrandr commands into it:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo xrandr --newmode "1280x1024_60.00"  109.00  1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync
sudo xrandr --addmode VGA1 1280x1024_60.00
```

- Make the script executable with `chmod +x xrandr.sh`
- Search for "Startup Applications" in the dash, run it, and add the script as a startup application.

The commands will now run every time you log into your account.

**NOTE:** You don't use `sudo` when executing `xrandr` commands.

Comment: Hi DevRobot ,do i create a bash script by creating a texfile and put after the name of the file .sh?  What is chmod +x? do i have to type that plus name of the .sh file in the terminal? Sorry for all the questions , but because i saw what you are telling me to do already in a different  topic, and tried that already, but failed because I must have been doing something wrong. I am a noob. Could you maybe explain step by step on how I have to proceed. thanks a lot.

Comment: @GianlucaMirci first comment - yes. second comment - the `chmod +x` makes the file executable. Include the `.sh` part in the command.

Comment: Hi DevRobot, that didnt work. I also notice than when i double click xrandr.sh file I created it should also set the resolution to 1280x1024 but it  opens in a text document instead. So what I think is that that is the reason it doesnt work at startup. perhaps something is not right with the .sh file I created. I did put it a startup programs just like you said I also made it executable.

Comment: @GianlucaMirci are you using gnome or the default unity?

Comment: I am using unity.