# xrandr settings lost after restart Ubuntu 16.04 with Ultrawide Monitor

Tags: 16.04, display, display-resolution, amd-graphics, xrandr

I'm trying yet again to switch from Windows to Linux and ran into the follwoing problem: 
I have a LG 29UM55 Ultrawide Monitor with a Radeon HD5450 card on Ubuntu 16.04. After a couple of hours reading through posts and trying out things I got it working by reducing the refresh rate to 40Hz. Unfortunately after a restart I have to do the whole "xrandr-thing" again, means it lost the resolution again.
I found some posts suggesting to edit the `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.config`
file but it just won't work! I played around a with it a bit but without success.

```
$ cvt 2560 1080 40  
# 2560x1080 39.93 Hz (CVT) hsync: 44.25 kHz; pclk: 147.25 MHz
Modeline "2560x1080_40.00"  147.25  2560 2680 2944 3328  1080 1083 1093 1108 -hsync +vsync

$ sudo xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_40.00" 147.25 2560 2680 2944 3328 1080 1083 1093 1108 -hsync +vsync

$ sudo xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1080_40.00

$ xrandr  
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2560 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
HDMI-0 connected primary 2560x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 677mm x 290mm
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94    30.00    29.97  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.08    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
   2560x1080_40.00  39.93* 
 DVI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
 VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

That's what I put into the `10-monitor.config` file

```
Section "Monitor"  
  Identifier "Monitor0"  
  Modeline "2560x1080_40.00" 147.25 2560 2680 2944 3328 1080 1083 1093   1108 -hsync +vsync  
EndSection  

Section "Screen"  
  Identifier "Screen0"  
  Device "HDMI-0"  
  Monitor "Monitor0"  
  DefaultDepth 24  
  SubSection "Display"  
    Depth 24    
    Modes "2560x1080_40.00"    
  EndSubSection  
EndSection
```

Comment: The thing is that `xrandr` commands need to run on user level, to prevent being overruled by (other) local procedures after log in. Running them on log in, as described here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/637911/how-to-run-xrandr-commands-at-startup-in-ubuntu is your best option I am afraid. I am pretty sure you don't need the sudo then btw.

Comment: P.S. I marked it as a dupe, but if it doesn't solve your issue in any way, please leave a comment.

Comment: The startup script does the trick for me! Sudo isn't needed indeed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Don't mention it, glad it works :)