# Persist xrandr changes on Kubuntu 16.10

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, xrandr, startup-applications

I've been using Ubuntu-derived Linux distributions for a little while now (first Mint 17.3 and then Ubuntu 14.04) and I've always had this problem where the OS/X11 doesn't list 2560x1440 as a valid resolution on my second monitor (its a 4K display running over HDMI, so I prefer running in 1440p@60hz instead of 4K@30hz).

I've always fixed this problem by essentially following the steps in [this article](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Setting_xrandr_changes_persistently). e.g. create the `.xprofile` file and add the necessary `xrandr` commands so that it loads up when X loads up.

However I recently tried to do the same on Kubuntu 16.10 and for whatever reason, Kubuntu doesn't seem to be running the `.xprofile` file. I've tried making the changes straight to SDDM's Xsession entry points and a few other places that looked promising, but the `2560x1440` never shows up in the list.

If I just run the commands from a terminal once my user session has started up, it goes into 2560x1440 mode. If I put it as a autostart script from the System Settings (or wherever) it does NOT work. It almost seems like there is a process that runs *after* I make this resolution change and moves it back to 4K@30hz.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Hmm, consider rephrasing your question to something like "How to configure xrandr custom display mode persistently?" (suggestion). Also, it appears KDE/Kubuntu agnostic and instead be EDID/DDC-over-HDMI related (because DP works fine).

Comment: So I've tried a couple other Linux distributions and they all have the same underlying resolution problem so its definitely EDID/DDC related.However, in all other distributions (Ubuntu-based), I can fix it permanently using the .xprofile trick. So at least on the surface, it looks to me to be related to how KDE/Kubuntu interacts with X. But I will make changes to the question to cover this as well.

Comment: Could you provide the exact set of commands you use ?

Comment: Here we go: http://askubuntu.com/q/637911 Read section: ***Important note: adding xrandr commands to Startup Applications*** of this answer:  http://askubuntu.com/a/637921/72216. Distro is irrelevant; works similar on all. If it worked without the break, so far, you were simply lucky.

Comment: @JacobVlijm, I haven't tried the pause, but in all honesty, almost *everything* on the internet talks about .xprofile, xsession.d, xstart, and various parts of the X initialization scripts (which are annoyingly different between distributions). On my Ubuntu machine, *both* xprofile and xsession.d changes work, but on the Kubuntu machine, *neither* word. I guess that's the real question, how is the Kubuntu X startup different that I can't make it understand XProfile and its friends?

Comment: No, that's not the question. Especially with multi monitor, you can be pretty sure local procedures will overrule whatever you set,  *unless* the local procedures just confirm what was already there. If settings are not stored automatically, it is practically always the result of minor incompatibilities between driver and screen, causing jumping back to defaults *unless* you run your xrandr commands after these procedures on log in. Just try and you will see :) it is all a matter of timing.