# How do I run script on startup to fix screen orientation issue?

Tags: scripts, startup, systemd

I've be looking for a way to run a script on startup but all old threads I've found on the subject seem to be before systemd came in and none of the answers I've found seem to work anymore. I'm new to Linux operating systems and I'm not sure where to look for instructions on how to do this under systemd.

For a bit of back story I recently replaced Windows on a little tablet/laptop with Ubuntu and I've found that on start up the screen orientation is the wrong way around, meaning every time I log in I have to enter `xrandr -o right` into the terminal, which is a bit annoying to do every time.

Additionally, if anyone has any resources for beginners entering Linux, I'd love to see them! I'm currently on a university degree and the programming side of things is all done on Ubuntu so it would be great to become more adept at using the system.

Thanks.

Comment: There are tons and tons of [Linux Tutorials](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=linux+tutorials&oq=linux+tutorials&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i65l2j0l2.6308j0j1&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) on the web. Would advise you to start from **[here](https://www.tecmint.com/60-commands-of-linux-a-guide-from-newbies-to-system-administrator/)**.

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/719157/507051) on the canonical post I linked covers `systemd` quite well.

Comment: Xrandr commands, or screen- and keyboard related commands in general are a specific categorie, need a slightly different approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same issue within Ubuntu 16.04. Apparently it is a bug, *something* saves wrong value of the display orientation into the file `~/.config/monitors.xml`. So if you execute `xrandr -o right` on startup the orientation value will be override when you login and the file `monitors.xml` is readied.

To fix this for a certain user, just add the following Cron job - `crontab -e`:

```
@reboot sed -i 's#<rotation>.*</rotation>#<rotation>normal</rotation>#' "$HOME/.config/monitors.xml" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

- Replace `normal` with your desired orientation.
- This command will substitute `<rotation>something</rotation>` with `<rotation>desired value</rotation>` within the file `~/.config/monitors.xml`.

Unfortunately this workaround will fix the problem only when you start or reboot the system. When you log-out and log-in the problem may appear again. To fix this you can add your `xrandr` command in the [Startup Applications](https://askubuntu.com/q/48321/566421).

Comment: Xrandr commands, or screen- and keyboard related commands in general are a specific categorie, need a slightly different approach. Your description is correct, but I am not sure the solution is the simplest for the case :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm, the current issue is really annoying... If you just put `xrandr` command in the Startup applications, when you run the system and log-in - `monitors.xml` will be executed first and you will get wrong orientation. Then will be executed the `xrandr` command from Startup applications and the screen will be rotated once again. This take 1-3 second at all an it is comparable with the boot time of fast laptop with SSD...

Comment: I know, the simplest solution is to add a tiny break to the startup command. https://askubuntu.com/questions/637911/how-to-run-xrandr-commands-at-startup-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

Example startup script:

1. First create a systemd startup script eg.disk-space-check.service into `/etc/systemd/system/` directory with content:

   ```
   [Unit]
   After=mysql.service
   [Service]
   ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/disk-space-check.sh
   [Install]
   WantedBy=default.target
   ```
2. Install systemd service unit and enable it:

   ```
   chmod 664 /etc/systemd/system/disk-space-check.service
   systemctl daemon-reload
   systemctl enable disk-space-check.service
   ```

More explanation about you can read in this links:

- [How to Write Startup scripts for systemd ?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47695/how-to-write-startup-script-for-systemd)
- [How to auto-execute shell scripts at startup boot on systemd ?](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-automatically-execute-shell-script-at-startup-boot-on-systemd-linux)