# Screen resolution not appearing

Tags: display, display-resolution

So the screen resolution of my monitor is missing and I have just installed Ubuntu 18.04, only some smaller resolutions appear.
I manually added my screen resolution with xrandr and then I'm able to select it and everything is great.
Upon restarting the PC, it defaults back to the smaller resolution 1024x768 and the option for 1600x900 (my resolution) is gone again. Is there a way to have this setting changed permanently? I read about editting the xorg.conf file in /etc/X11/xorg.conf but I don't know how to edit it :(

Also, is there a way to tell if I'm using the latest GPU drivers? I have an AMD Radeon R7 360.

Comment: You can make your xrandr commands to be executed every time you login or start the computer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/637911/how-to-run-xrandr-commands-at-startup-in-ubuntu. I would suggest the second answer with `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/` involved as it should work for all users. The first answer is only per user, which puts the script in startup apps.

Comment: you know how I solved it? By ticking the checkbox about restricted extras in the ubuntu installation (unticked by default).