# Setting monitor scaling to 200% with xrandr

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, display-resolution, xrandr, scaling

I have two 4k monitors one called DP-4, the other DP-2 (plus the Laptop's internal display). Using `xrandr` (or another command line tool) I would like to arrange them as in the following and *also* set the scaling to 200%:

[image: screenshot showing monitors as I want them]

This almost works with this command:

```sh
xrandr \
  --output "DP-4" --primary --pos "0x0"  \
  --output "DP-2" --pos "3840x0" \
  --output eDP-1-1 --off
```

The only thing not working is setting the scaling of both DP-4 and DP-2 to 200% with `xrandr`. How can I do this?

PS: I am on Ubuntu 19.10 with Gnome and X (not Wayland, because I use an NVIDIA card).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just missing the `--scale 2x2` argument. So use:

```
xrandr \
  --output DP-4 --primary --pos 0x0 --scale 2x2 \
  --output DP-2 --pos 3840x0 --scale 2x2 \
  --output eDP-1-1 --off
```

**Note:** Double quoting the monitor and position is unnecessary so I removed the `"`.

Comment: Does this work for you? My desktop goes crazy when I enter this command. Everything is very small and I have to restart/kill X, see these two screenshots: https://imgur.com/a/MejnKwP

Not sure this is just a nvidia driver issue because when entering via Ubuntu's display settings manually it works fine (Problem is just that these settings are always forgotten once entered)

Comment: @nachtigall It works for others but personally I use scaling of 1.38 setup in tweak tool. As far as persistence of xrandr settings see: [How to run xrandr commands at startup in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/637911/how-to-run-xrandr-commands-at-startup-in-ubuntu)

Comment: yeah, running `xrandr` at startup is my goal if it would only be working. Thanks for the link.

Comment: "I use scaling of 1.38 setup in tweak tool" – do you mean font scaling? This seems different from whole desktop/monitor scaling. My font scaling in the Tweaks tools is still 1,00 besides my Display settings being 200% (set manually).

Comment: Yes font, scaling set to 1.38. I leave my monitor set at 3840x2160 so 4K video can be displayed and 4K wallpaper, etc. I've also made my cursor, icons and title bars larger. In Chrome and Firefox I have web pages zoomed at 110%. Then a separate app gradually adjusts brightness and gamma individually for three monitors at dawn and dusk over 1 to 2 hour period. It's perfect for me but others might not be so picky...

Comment: Using `2x2` seems the correct answer, but either Gnome or NVIDIA drivers are buggy. So it still does not work for me.

Comment: `--scale 0.5` is a similar result as setting `Settings>Display>Scale` to `200%`, however using something different than `--scale 1` always leads to blurry results, so use the Settings-dialog, this does not blur the result

Answer (score 2):

Adding on @WinEunuuchs2Unix's answer, use `--scale 0.5x0.5` command

Like this:

```
xrandr \
  --output "DP-4" --primary --pos "0x0" --scale 0.5x0.5 \
  --output "DP-2" --pos "3840x0" \
  --output eDP-1-1 --off
```

Comment: If I use `--scale 0.5` the result gets very blurry, how can I force that in upscaling 1pixel get rendered by 2x2 Pixel without any smoothing. So a black-white image should still not contain any gray.

Comment: `--scale 0.5 --filter nearest`
Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/GPDPocket/comments/90bras/tip_nearestneighbor_xrandr_display_scaling/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Answer (score 2):

### Why you should use Wayland (with noveau) instead of x11 on Nvidia Graphics cards

I personally recommend to use  wayland (with noveau) instead of x11 (with nvidia), because on wayland you do not have any quality-losses as with `xranxr --scale`, see https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xrandr/-/issues/56 .

### Why `--scale` of `xrandr` leads to a blurry results

If you are using "--scale 0.5" you send one frame-buffer-pixel to four real pixels, and it adds a bilinear filter making it blurry. If you are using "--scale 2" you render 4 frame-buffer-pixels for one physical pixel, leading to (1) an useless overload the graphics card and (2) because of the bilinear filtering it is blurry and worsens the result.
With `--filter nearest` you can avoid the blurriness, however the result is much better, but still unacceptable for reading fonts or graphics design.

### Further advantages of Wayland

Wayland (with nouveau) has many advantages such as (a) factural scaling 100%,125%,150%,175%,200% (b) screenwise scaling (c) a lossless-scaling, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/660345/241592 for details.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know. I'd love to switch to Wayland but as far as I know performance of noveau is much poorer than the closed nvidia version. And the closed nvidia version does not (yet) support wayland. Or has this changed?

Comment: @nachtigall Yes, Nvidia performs better than Noveau (iff no scaling), however Nvidia is also buggier than Noveau. If you do not need any scaling I would use X11 (with Nvidia) because X11 is more stable/compatible to most applications. However if you need scaling you have to switch to Wayland (with noveau), otherwise you will have drastic performance and quality-losses.
(1) If you want scaling use Wayland
(2) If you want stability use X11 with Noveau
(3) If you don't need scaling and prefer performance over stability use Nvidia