# xrandr - different effect when put in .xprofile

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, display, xrandr

I have a new 4k monitor. I'd like to zoom its desktop by 25%. After boot or logging in, I usually run this command manually:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --fb 4992x1728 --mode 3840x2160 --scale 0.8x0.8 --pos 0x0 --primary \
   --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --scale 1x1 --pos 3072x0
```

It sets up my GUI, resolutions, and positions of two monitors around a virtual desktop exactly as I expect.

The problem is this command doesn't work if I put it in the `~/.xprofile`. The outcome seems to vary between relogs: sometimes the screen is not scaled at all, sometimes it is but desktop locations around the virtual desktop are not clear. If the `~/.xprofile` is not a correct place to configure the GUI when X session starts, what is the alternative? Is it just the `~/.profile`? I don't know if `~/.profile` is run only once per user session or multiple times. It might be important because when `xrandr` is run multiple times, it may also cause problems. In terms of errors regarding the command in the `~/.xprofile`, how can I know what exactly happens when X session starts. Is there any log file?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run xrandr commands at startup in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/637911/how-to-run-xrandr-commands-at-startup-in-ubuntu)

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Yes, it explains the problem and gives an answer but it is more like hacking rather solving a problem. I could equally be good to make a script and run it by myself when X is ready. Anyway thanks for the link!

Comment: I added an answer which I think is the direction you want to go in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method used by others (linked in comments) is considered "hack" by OP. Which I guess it might be.

Using X configuration file which is loaded before login screen and not after login can be done here:

```
$ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "DP-1-1"
    Modeline "3840x2160_54.00"  637.50  3840 4152 4568 5296  2160 2163 2168 2230 -hsync +vsync
    Option "PreferredMode" "3840x2160_54.00"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "modesetting"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
    Option "AccelMethod" "None"
    Option "TearFree"    "true"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
    Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
    Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
EndSection
```

[Xorg Monitor options](https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/man/man5/xorg.conf.5.xhtml#heading12)

Comment: Thanks for this. I don't know what some numbers correspond to but I'll check them and the link as soon as I get back home :)

Comment: I actually use the method you consider a "hack" by using a bash function for setting my own three monitors up. I do this on the odd occassion the settings get jumbled up when a TV is turned off at the wrong time. The bash function saves me from rebooting or remembering all the setup commands. I only used the above xorg configuration file when I had to. The link has some fascinating information though.

Comment: In the end, maybe that hack is not too bad. It’s only one command anyway! Cheers!