# A way to pin the screen refresh rate?

Tags: display, display-resolution, flicker

So I've got a HP Probook 440 G6 with a full HD display. By default, Ubuntu 18.04 uses 1920x1080 resolution and 120.02Hz refresh rate. I believe (or found info about it somewhere) that high (and rather non standard) refresh rate is causing screen flickering sometimes. So I set it to 59.96Hz manually on every boot and it seems to solve the issue.

I would want it to be automated how can I do that.
Also are there recommended values for full HD screens?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run xrandr commands at startup in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/637911/how-to-run-xrandr-commands-at-startup-in-ubuntu)

Comment: It does partially. Thank you. What about the recommended defaults for Full HD screens?

Comment: I would recommend 1920x1080 at the highest refresh rate that doesn't cause screen flicker. In my case it is 60 Hz.