# How to set xrandr screen brightness to run on startup?

Tags: kubuntu, 19.10

I use this command everytime I login because the screen is just too bright.

```
xrandr --output HDMI-A-0 --brightness 0.90
```

How can I make this command run on startup?
I use Kubuntu 19.10.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run xrandr commands at startup in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/637911/how-to-run-xrandr-commands-at-startup-in-ubuntu) ([relevant comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/637911/how-to-run-xrandr-commands-at-startup-in-ubuntu#comment1598624_637921) if you use the first answer)

Answer (score 1):

you should create a file named rc.local in /etc folder
and give it executable permissions...

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

file needs to be look like this

```
#!/bin/bash
xrandr --output HDMI-A-0 --brightness 0.90
```

use Ctrl+x to save and exit click Y Enter to confirm ...

Note:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-A-0 --brightness 0.90 --gamma 1.05:1.00:0.95
```

also works to adjust color using R:G:B channels and a little bit sharpness when you combine with --gamma I think ...

for better contrast I use this :

```
xrandr --output DVI-D-0 --brightness 1.1 --gamma 0.9:0.9:0.9
```

for more cold colors :

```
xrandr --output HDMI-A-0 --brightness 1.1 --gamma 0.85:0.85:0.9
```