# How to make xrandr settings persist over reboot?

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, xorg

Using nvidia drivers and a dual monitor setup (144hz + 60hz), I was finally able to enable 144 on my newer monitor using `xrandr --output HDMI-1 --primary --mode 1920x1080 --rate 144`.
However these changes don't persist over reboot and I have to enter it again. Is there a way to start these with the X server? I want this command to be executed for any user and as soon as my display manager starts.

Comment: Typically using venerable xorg.conf, see here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xrandr#Adding_undetected_resolutions. Else via autostart, see https://askubuntu.com/questions/637911/how-to-run-xrandr-commands-at-startup-in-ubuntu.

Comment: See here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xrandr#Permanently_adding_undetected_resolutions